# Click on a day By Color

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need help to click the day (date) that has Green Backround with js ...
Here's what I got on the HTML:

```html
    <td style="width: 50%" id="caldiv">
                        <div id="calendar" class="fc fc-ltr"><table class="fc-header" style="width:100%"><tr><td class="fc-header-left"><span class="fc-button fc-button-prev fc-state-default fc-corner-left fc-corner-right" unselectable="on" style="display: none;"><span class="fc-text-arrow">‹</span></span></td><td class="fc-header-center"><span class="fc-header-title"><h2>December 2019</h2></span></td><td class="fc-header-right"><span class="fc-button fc-button-next fc-state-default fc-corner-left fc-corner-right" unselectable="on"><span class="fc-text-arrow">›</span></span></td></tr></table><div class="fc-content" style="position: relative;"><div class="fc-view fc-view-month fc-grid" style="position:relative" unselectable="on"><div class="fc-event-container" style="position:absolute;z-index:8;top:0;left:0"></div><table class="fc-border-separate" style="width:100%" cellspacing="0"><thead><tr class="fc-first fc-last"><th class="fc-day-header fc-sun fc-widget-header fc-first" style="width: 51px;">Sun</th><th class="fc-day-header fc-mon fc-widget-header" style="width: 51px;">Mon</th><th class="fc-day-header fc-tue fc-widget-header" style="width: 51px;">Tue</th><th class="fc-day-header fc-wed fc-widget-header" style="width: 51px;">Wed</th><th class="fc-day-header fc-thu fc-widget-header" style="width: 51px;">Thu</th><th class="fc-day-header fc-fri fc-widget-header" style="width: 51px;">Fri</th><th class="fc-day-header fc-sat fc-widget-header fc-last">Sat</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr class="fc-week fc-first"><td class="fc-day fc-sun fc-widget-content fc-past fc-first" data-date="2019-12-01"><div style="min-height: 40px;"><div class="fc-day-number">1</div><div class="fc-day-content"><div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div></div></div></td><td class="fc-day fc-mon fc-widget-content fc-past" data-date="2019-12-02"><div><div class="fc-day-number">2</div><div class="fc-day-content"><div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div></div></div></td><td class="fc-day fc-tue fc-widget-content fc-past" data-date="2019-12-03"><div><div class="fc-day-number">3</div><div class="fc-day-content"><div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div></div></div></td><td class="fc-day fc-wed fc-widget-content fc-past" data-date="2019-12-04"><div><div class="fc-day-number">4</div><div class="fc-day-content"><div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div></div></div></td><td class="fc-day fc-thu fc-widget-content fc-past" data-date="2019-12-05"><div><div class="fc-day-number">5</div><div class="fc-day-content"><div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div></div></div></td><td class="fc-day fc-fri fc-widget-content fc-past" data-date="2019-12-06"><div><div class="fc-day-number">6</div><div class="fc-day-content"><div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div></div></div></td><td class="fc-day fc-sat fc-widget-content fc-past fc-last" data-date="2019-12-07"><div><div class="fc-day-number">7</div><div class="fc-day-content"><div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div></div></div></td></tr><tr class="fc-week"><td class="fc-day fc-sun fc-widget-content fc-past fc-first" data-date="2019-12-08"><div style="min-height: 39px;"><div class="fc-day-number">8</div><div class="fc-day-content"><div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div></div></div></td><td class="fc-day fc-mon fc-widget-content fc-past" data-date="2019-12-09"><div><div class="fc-day-number">9</div><div class="fc-day-content"><div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div></div></div></td><td class="fc-day fc-tue fc-widget-content fc-past" data-date="2019-12-10"><div><div class="fc-day-number">10</div><div class="fc-day-content"><div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div></div></div></td><td class="fc-day fc-wed fc-widget-content fc-past" data-date="2019-12-11"><div><div class="fc-day-number">11</div><div class="fc-day-content"><div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div></div></div></td><td class="fc-day fc-thu fc-widget-content fc-past" data-date="2019-12-12"><div><div class="fc-day-number">12</div><div class="fc-day-content"><div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div></div></div></td><td class="fc-day fc-fri fc-widget-content fc-past" data-date="2019-12-13"><div><div class="fc-day-number">13</div><div class="fc-day-content"><div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div></div></div></td><td class="fc-day fc-sat fc-widget-content fc-past fc-last" data-date="2019-12-14"><div><div class="fc-day-number">14</div><div class="fc-day-content"><div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div></div></div></td></tr><tr class="fc-week"><td class="fc-day fc-sun fc-widget-content fc-past fc-first" data-date="2019-12-15"><div style="min-height: 39px;"><div class="fc-day-number">15</div><div class="fc-day-content"><div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div></div></div></td><td class="fc-day fc-mon fc-widget-content fc-past" data-date="2019-12-16"><div><div class="fc-day-number">16</div><div class="fc-day-content"><div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div></div></div></td><td class="fc-day fc-tue fc-widget-content fc-past" data-date="2019-12-17"><div><div class="fc-day-number">17</div><div class="fc-day-content"><div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div></div></div></td><td class="fc-day fc-wed fc-widget-content fc-past" data-date="2019-12-18"><div><div class="fc-day-number">18</div><div class="fc-day-content"><div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div></div></div></td><td class="fc-day fc-thu fc-widget-content fc-past" data-date="2019-12-19"><div><div class="fc-day-number">19</div><div class="fc-day-content"><div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div></div></div></td><td class="fc-day fc-fri fc-widget-content fc-past" data-date="2019-12-20" style="color: rgb(255, 106, 106);"><div><div class="fc-day-number">20</div><div class="fc-day-content"><div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div></div></div></td><td class="fc-day fc-sat fc-widget-content fc-past fc-last" data-date="2019-12-21" style="color: rgb(255, 106, 106);"><div><div class="fc-day-number">21</div><div class="fc-day-content"><div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div></div></div></td></tr><tr class="fc-week"><td class="fc-day fc-sun fc-widget-content fc-past fc-first" data-date="2019-12-22"><div style="min-height: 39px;"><div class="fc-day-number">22</div><div class="fc-day-content"><div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div></div></div></td><td class="fc-day fc-mon fc-widget-content fc-past" data-date="2019-12-23"><div><div class="fc-day-number">23</div><div class="fc-day-content"><div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div></div></div></td><td class="fc-day fc-tue fc-widget-content fc-past" data-date="2019-12-24"><div><div class="fc-day-number">24</div><div class="fc-day-content"><div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div></div></div></td><td class="fc-day fc-wed fc-widget-content fc-past" data-date="2019-12-25"><div><div class="fc-day-number">25</div><div class="fc-day-content"><div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div></div></div></td><td class="fc-day fc-thu fc-widget-content fc-past" data-date="2019-12-26"><div><div class="fc-day-number">26</div><div class="fc-day-content"><div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div></div></div></td><td class="fc-day fc-fri fc-widget-content fc-past" data-date="2019-12-27" style="color: rgb(255, 106, 106);"><div><div class="fc-day-number">27</div><div class="fc-day-content"><div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div></div></div></td><td class="fc-day fc-sat fc-widget-content fc-past fc-last" data-date="2019-12-28" style="color: rgb(255, 106, 106);"><div><div class="fc-day-number">28</div><div class="fc-day-content"><div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div></div></div></td></tr><tr class="fc-week"><td class="fc-day fc-sun fc-widget-content fc-today fc-state-highlight fc-first" data-date="2019-12-29"><div style="min-height: 39px;"><div class="fc-day-number">29</div><div class="fc-day-content"><div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div></div></div></td><td class="fc-day fc-mon fc-widget-content fc-future" data-date="2019-12-30" style="background-color: rgb(188, 237, 145); cursor: pointer;"><div><div class="fc-day-number">30</div><div class="fc-day-content"><div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div></div></div></td><td class="fc-day fc-tue fc-widget-content fc-future" data-date="2019-12-31" style="background-color: rgb(188, 237, 145); cursor: pointer;"><div><div class="fc-day-number">31</div><div class="fc-day-content"><div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div></div></div></td><td class="fc-day fc-wed fc-widget-content fc-other-month fc-future" data-date="2020-01-01" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><div><div class="fc-day-number">1</div><div class="fc-day-content"><div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div></div></div></td><td class="fc-day fc-thu fc-widget-content fc-other-month fc-future" data-date="2020-01-02" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><div><div class="fc-day-number">2</div><div class="fc-day-content"><div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div></div></div></td><td class="fc-day fc-fri fc-widget-content fc-other-month fc-future" data-date="2020-01-03" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><div><div class="fc-day-number">3</div><div class="fc-day-content"><div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div></div></div></td><td class="fc-day fc-sat fc-widget-content fc-other-month fc-future fc-last" data-date="2020-01-04" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><div><div class="fc-day-number">4</div><div class="fc-day-content"><div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div></div></div></td></tr><tr class="fc-week fc-last"><td class="fc-day fc-sun fc-widget-content fc-other-month fc-future fc-first" data-date="2020-01-05" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><div style="min-height: 41px;"><div class="fc-day-number">5</div><div class="fc-day-content"><div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div></div></div></td><td class="fc-day fc-mon fc-widget-content fc-other-month fc-future" data-date="2020-01-06" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><div><div class="fc-day-number">6</div><div class="fc-day-content"><div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div></div></div></td><td class="fc-day fc-tue fc-widget-content fc-other-month fc-future" data-date="2020-01-07" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><div><div class="fc-day-number">7</div><div class="fc-day-content"><div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div></div></div></td><td class="fc-day fc-wed fc-widget-content fc-other-month fc-future" data-date="2020-01-08" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><div><div class="fc-day-number">8</div><div class="fc-day-content"><div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div></div></div></td><td class="fc-day fc-thu fc-widget-content fc-other-month fc-future" data-date="2020-01-09" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><div><div class="fc-day-number">9</div><div class="fc-day-content"><div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div></div></div></td><td class="fc-day fc-fri fc-widget-content fc-other-month fc-future" data-date="2020-01-10" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><div><div class="fc-day-number">10</div><div class="fc-day-content"><div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div></div></div></td><td class="fc-day fc-sat fc-widget-content fc-other-month fc-future fc-last" data-date="2020-01-11" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><div><div class="fc-day-number">11</div><div class="fc-day-content"><div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div></div></div></td></tr></tbody></table></div></div></div>
                    </td>
```

Here What i Tried :

```
document.getElementById('calendar.fc-day-number').style="background-color: rgb(188, 237, 145); );".click();
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Your html is not valid. Please post the correct html.

Comment: Done my friend Thank you

Comment: Unless you're unit-testing - you're doing something basically wrong. No legit program should work based on some logic happening based on a background color of an element...

Comment: Looks like you're using FullCalendar plugin. please post JS code.

Comment: Also posting hundreds of lines of HTML makes no sense. Create for testing purpose a couple of them, create the needed JS that accomplishes the desired and than you simply port it to the large scale.

Comment: @Aheb great hint... Seems like OP triggers some JS *before* the actual plugin has finished doing its magic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve what you are asking.

```
// Select all day elements
const days = document.querySelectorAll('.fc-day')

// Search for the element with the right background color
for (let item of days) {
  if(item.style.backgroundColor === 'rgb(188, 237, 145)') {
    item.click()
  }
}
```

I'd strongly recommend against using `style` for selecting elements in your HTML document. I'd be a better option to add to these green elements either a `data-selected` attribute or a css class (e.g.) `.selected` so that your css query is more expressive and maintainable. You could do something like

```
// Search all elements with data-selected="true"
const days = document.querySelectorAll('.fc-day[data-selected="true"]')
for (let item of days) {
    item.click()
}
```

Comment: The date isnt Choosing ... notihng happen

Comment: @AJX As others have commented on your original question, this seems to be a problem with the way you're using the calendar plugin. Nothing is happening because no event handler is attached. If you add an `onclick="alert("Hello")`
to any of those green dates, then you will see that they are clicked.

Comment: i will check that and see

Comment: The Date isnt Clicking at all its not even showing the alert

Answer (score 1):

I recommand using class or data attribute instead of styles (I hope you're doing this only for testing).

The code below will alert selected value only when available (based on available class in parent container), the logic of click listener is in a function so you can change the alert with code that fits your need, for instance to save the value into an input ...

see updated snippet :

```js
var days = document.getElementsByClassName('fc-day-number');

var myFunction = function() {
    if(this.parentNode.parentNode.classList.contains("available")) {
       // your logic goes here
       alert(this.textContent);
    } 
    
};

for (var i = 0; i < days.length; i++) {
    days[i].addEventListener('click', myFunction, false);
}
```

```html
<td style="width: 50%" id="caldiv">
    <div id="calendar" class="fc fc-ltr">
        <table class="fc-header" style="width:100%">
            <tr>
                <td class="fc-header-left"><span class="fc-button fc-button-prev fc-state-default fc-corner-left fc-corner-right" unselectable="on" style="display: none;"><span class="fc-text-arrow">‹</span></span>
                </td>
                <td class="fc-header-center"><span class="fc-header-title"><h2>December 2019</h2></span></td>
                <td class="fc-header-right"><span class="fc-button fc-button-next fc-state-default fc-corner-left fc-corner-right" unselectable="on"><span class="fc-text-arrow">›</span></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div class="fc-content" style="position: relative;">
            <div class="fc-view fc-view-month fc-grid" style="position:relative" unselectable="on">
                <div class="fc-event-container" style="position:absolute;z-index:8;top:0;left:0"></div>
                <table class="fc-border-separate" style="width:100%" cellspacing="0">
                    <thead>
                        <tr class="fc-first fc-last">
                            <th class="fc-day-header fc-sun fc-widget-header fc-first" style="width: 51px;">Sun</th>
                            <th class="fc-day-header fc-mon fc-widget-header" style="width: 51px;">Mon</th>
                            <th class="fc-day-header fc-tue fc-widget-header" style="width: 51px;">Tue</th>
                            <th class="fc-day-header fc-wed fc-widget-header" style="width: 51px;">Wed</th>
                            <th class="fc-day-header fc-thu fc-widget-header" style="width: 51px;">Thu</th>
                            <th class="fc-day-header fc-fri fc-widget-header" style="width: 51px;">Fri</th>
                            <th class="fc-day-header fc-sat fc-widget-header fc-last">Sat</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr class="fc-week fc-first">
                            <td class="fc-day fc-sun fc-widget-content fc-past fc-first" data-date="2019-12-01">
                                <div style="min-height: 40px;">
                                    <div class="fc-day-number">1</div>
                                    <div class="fc-day-content">
                                        <div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="fc-day fc-mon fc-widget-content fc-past" data-date="2019-12-02">
                                <div>
                                    <div class="fc-day-number">2</div>
                                    <div class="fc-day-content">
                                        <div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="fc-day fc-tue fc-widget-content fc-past" data-date="2019-12-03">
                                <div>
                                    <div class="fc-day-number">3</div>
                                    <div class="fc-day-content">
                                        <div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="fc-day fc-wed fc-widget-content fc-past" data-date="2019-12-04">
                                <div>
                                    <div class="fc-day-number">4</div>
                                    <div class="fc-day-content">
                                        <div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="fc-day fc-thu fc-widget-content fc-past" data-date="2019-12-05">
                                <div>
                                    <div class="fc-day-number">5</div>
                                    <div class="fc-day-content">
                                        <div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="fc-day fc-fri fc-widget-content fc-past" data-date="2019-12-06">
                                <div>
                                    <div class="fc-day-number">6</div>
                                    <div class="fc-day-content">
                                        <div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="fc-day fc-sat fc-widget-content fc-past fc-last" data-date="2019-12-07">
                                <div>
                                    <div class="fc-day-number">7</div>
                                    <div class="fc-day-content">
                                        <div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="fc-week">
                            <td class="fc-day fc-sun fc-widget-content fc-past fc-first" data-date="2019-12-08">
                                <div style="min-height: 39px;">
                                    <div class="fc-day-number">8</div>
                                    <div class="fc-day-content">
                                        <div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="fc-day fc-mon fc-widget-content fc-past" data-date="2019-12-09">
                                <div>
                                    <div class="fc-day-number">9</div>
                                    <div class="fc-day-content">
                                        <div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="fc-day fc-tue fc-widget-content fc-past" data-date="2019-12-10">
                                <div>
                                    <div class="fc-day-number">10</div>
                                    <div class="fc-day-content">
                                        <div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="fc-day fc-wed fc-widget-content fc-past" data-date="2019-12-11">
                                <div>
                                    <div class="fc-day-number">11</div>
                                    <div class="fc-day-content">
                                        <div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="fc-day fc-thu fc-widget-content fc-past" data-date="2019-12-12">
                                <div>
                                    <div class="fc-day-number">12</div>
                                    <div class="fc-day-content">
                                        <div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="fc-day fc-fri fc-widget-content fc-past" data-date="2019-12-13">
                                <div>
                                    <div class="fc-day-number">13</div>
                                    <div class="fc-day-content">
                                        <div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="fc-day fc-sat fc-widget-content fc-past fc-last" data-date="2019-12-14">
                                <div>
                                    <div class="fc-day-number">14</div>
                                    <div class="fc-day-content">
                                        <div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="fc-week">
                            <td class="fc-day fc-sun fc-widget-content fc-past fc-first" data-date="2019-12-15">
                                <div style="min-height: 39px;">
                                    <div class="fc-day-number">15</div>
                                    <div class="fc-day-content">
                                        <div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="fc-day fc-mon fc-widget-content fc-past" data-date="2019-12-16">
                                <div>
                                    <div class="fc-day-number">16</div>
                                    <div class="fc-day-content">
                                        <div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="fc-day fc-tue fc-widget-content fc-past" data-date="2019-12-17">
                                <div>
                                    <div class="fc-day-number">17</div>
                                    <div class="fc-day-content">
                                        <div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="fc-day fc-wed fc-widget-content fc-past" data-date="2019-12-18">
                                <div>
                                    <div class="fc-day-number">18</div>
                                    <div class="fc-day-content">
                                        <div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="fc-day fc-thu fc-widget-content fc-past" data-date="2019-12-19">
                                <div>
                                    <div class="fc-day-number">19</div>
                                    <div class="fc-day-content">
                                        <div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="fc-day fc-fri fc-widget-content fc-past" data-date="2019-12-20" style="color: rgb(255, 106, 106);">
                                <div>
                                    <div class="fc-day-number">20</div>
                                    <div class="fc-day-content">
                                        <div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="fc-day fc-sat fc-widget-content fc-past fc-last" data-date="2019-12-21" style="color: rgb(255, 106, 106);">
                                <div>
                                    <div class="fc-day-number">21</div>
                                    <div class="fc-day-content">
                                        <div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="fc-week">
                            <td class="fc-day fc-sun fc-widget-content fc-past fc-first" data-date="2019-12-22">
                                <div style="min-height: 39px;">
                                    <div class="fc-day-number">22</div>
                                    <div class="fc-day-content">
                                        <div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="fc-day fc-mon fc-widget-content fc-past" data-date="2019-12-23">
                                <div>
                                    <div class="fc-day-number">23</div>
                                    <div class="fc-day-content">
                                        <div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="fc-day fc-tue fc-widget-content fc-past" data-date="2019-12-24">
                                <div>
                                    <div class="fc-day-number">24</div>
                                    <div class="fc-day-content">
                                        <div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="fc-day fc-wed fc-widget-content fc-past" data-date="2019-12-25">
                                <div>
                                    <div class="fc-day-number">25</div>
                                    <div class="fc-day-content">
                                        <div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="fc-day fc-thu fc-widget-content fc-past" data-date="2019-12-26">
                                <div>
                                    <div class="fc-day-number">26</div>
                                    <div class="fc-day-content">
                                        <div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="fc-day fc-fri fc-widget-content fc-past" data-date="2019-12-27" style="color: rgb(255, 106, 106);">
                                <div>
                                    <div class="fc-day-number">27</div>
                                    <div class="fc-day-content">
                                        <div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="fc-day fc-sat fc-widget-content fc-past fc-last" data-date="2019-12-28" style="color: rgb(255, 106, 106);">
                                <div>
                                    <div class="fc-day-number">28</div>
                                    <div class="fc-day-content">
                                        <div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="fc-week">
                            <td class="fc-day fc-sun fc-widget-content fc-today fc-state-highlight fc-first" data-date="2019-12-29">
                                <div style="min-height: 39px;">
                                    <div class="fc-day-number">29</div>
                                    <div class="fc-day-content">
                                        <div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="fc-day fc-mon fc-widget-content fc-future available" data-date="2019-12-30" style="background-color: rgb(188, 237, 145); cursor: pointer;">
                                <div>
                                    <div class="fc-day-number">30</div>
                                    <div class="fc-day-content">
                                        <div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="fc-day fc-tue fc-widget-content fc-future available" data-date="2019-12-31" style="background-color: rgb(188, 237, 145); cursor: pointer;">
                                <div>
                                    <div class="fc-day-number">31</div>
                                    <div class="fc-day-content">
                                        <div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="fc-day fc-wed fc-widget-content fc-other-month fc-future" data-date="2020-01-01" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
                                <div>
                                    <div class="fc-day-number">1</div>
                                    <div class="fc-day-content">
                                        <div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="fc-day fc-thu fc-widget-content fc-other-month fc-future" data-date="2020-01-02" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
                                <div>
                                    <div class="fc-day-number">2</div>
                                    <div class="fc-day-content">
                                        <div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="fc-day fc-fri fc-widget-content fc-other-month fc-future" data-date="2020-01-03" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
                                <div>
                                    <div class="fc-day-number">3</div>
                                    <div class="fc-day-content">
                                        <div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="fc-day fc-sat fc-widget-content fc-other-month fc-future fc-last" data-date="2020-01-04" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
                                <div>
                                    <div class="fc-day-number">4</div>
                                    <div class="fc-day-content">
                                        <div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="fc-week fc-last">
                            <td class="fc-day fc-sun fc-widget-content fc-other-month fc-future fc-first" data-date="2020-01-05" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
                                <div style="min-height: 41px;">
                                    <div class="fc-day-number">5</div>
                                    <div class="fc-day-content">
                                        <div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="fc-day fc-mon fc-widget-content fc-other-month fc-future" data-date="2020-01-06" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
                                <div>
                                    <div class="fc-day-number">6</div>
                                    <div class="fc-day-content">
                                        <div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="fc-day fc-tue fc-widget-content fc-other-month fc-future" data-date="2020-01-07" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
                                <div>
                                    <div class="fc-day-number">7</div>
                                    <div class="fc-day-content">
                                        <div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="fc-day fc-wed fc-widget-content fc-other-month fc-future" data-date="2020-01-08" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
                                <div>
                                    <div class="fc-day-number">8</div>
                                    <div class="fc-day-content">
                                        <div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="fc-day fc-thu fc-widget-content fc-other-month fc-future" data-date="2020-01-09" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
                                <div>
                                    <div class="fc-day-number">9</div>
                                    <div class="fc-day-content">
                                        <div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="fc-day fc-fri fc-widget-content fc-other-month fc-future" data-date="2020-01-10" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
                                <div>
                                    <div class="fc-day-number">10</div>
                                    <div class="fc-day-content">
                                        <div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="fc-day fc-sat fc-widget-content fc-other-month fc-future fc-last" data-date="2020-01-11" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
                                <div>
                                    <div class="fc-day-number">11</div>
                                    <div class="fc-day-content">
                                        <div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have .fc-future class on green date. The optimal way to solve the question will be:

```
var firstGreenDate = document.querySelector('.fc-future');

firstGreenDate.addEventListener("click", function () {
    // Your custom code or action here
    alert("Clicked on the first green date!");
});
```

```js
var firstGreenDate = document.querySelector('.fc-future');

// Add a click event listener
firstGreenDate.addEventListener("click", function () {
    // Your custom code or action here
    alert("Clicked on the first green date!");
});
```

```html
<td style="width: 50%" id="caldiv">
                        <div id="calendar" class="fc fc-ltr"><table class="fc-header" style="width:100%"><tr><td class="fc-header-left"><span class="fc-button fc-button-prev fc-state-default fc-corner-left fc-corner-right" unselectable="on" style="display: none;"><span class="fc-text-arrow">‹</span></span></td><td class="fc-header-center"><span class="fc-header-title"><h2>December 2019</h2></span></td><td class="fc-header-right"><span class="fc-button fc-button-next fc-state-default fc-corner-left fc-corner-right" unselectable="on"><span class="fc-text-arrow">›</span></span></td></tr></table><div class="fc-content" style="position: relative;"><div class="fc-view fc-view-month fc-grid" style="position:relative" unselectable="on"><div class="fc-event-container" style="position:absolute;z-index:8;top:0;left:0"></div><table class="fc-border-separate" style="width:100%" cellspacing="0"><thead><tr class="fc-first fc-last"><th class="fc-day-header fc-sun fc-widget-header fc-first" style="width: 51px;">Sun</th><th class="fc-day-header fc-mon fc-widget-header" style="width: 51px;">Mon</th><th class="fc-day-header fc-tue fc-widget-header" style="width: 51px;">Tue</th><th class="fc-day-header fc-wed fc-widget-header" style="width: 51px;">Wed</th><th class="fc-day-header fc-thu fc-widget-header" style="width: 51px;">Thu</th><th class="fc-day-header fc-fri fc-widget-header" style="width: 51px;">Fri</th><th class="fc-day-header fc-sat fc-widget-header fc-last">Sat</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr class="fc-week fc-first"><td class="fc-day fc-sun fc-widget-content fc-past fc-first" data-date="2019-12-01"><div style="min-height: 40px;"><div class="fc-day-number">1</div><div class="fc-day-content"><div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div></div></div></td><td class="fc-day fc-mon fc-widget-content fc-past" data-date="2019-12-02"><div><div class="fc-day-number">2</div><div class="fc-day-content"><div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div></div></div></td><td class="fc-day fc-tue fc-widget-content fc-past" data-date="2019-12-03"><div><div class="fc-day-number">3</div><div class="fc-day-content"><div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div></div></div></td><td class="fc-day fc-wed fc-widget-content fc-past" data-date="2019-12-04"><div><div class="fc-day-number">4</div><div class="fc-day-content"><div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div></div></div></td><td class="fc-day fc-thu fc-widget-content fc-past" data-date="2019-12-05"><div><div class="fc-day-number">5</div><div class="fc-day-content"><div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div></div></div></td><td class="fc-day fc-fri fc-widget-content fc-past" data-date="2019-12-06"><div><div class="fc-day-number">6</div><div class="fc-day-content"><div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div></div></div></td><td class="fc-day fc-sat fc-widget-content fc-past fc-last" data-date="2019-12-07"><div><div class="fc-day-number">7</div><div class="fc-day-content"><div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div></div></div></td></tr><tr class="fc-week"><td class="fc-day fc-sun fc-widget-content fc-past fc-first" data-date="2019-12-08"><div style="min-height: 39px;"><div class="fc-day-number">8</div><div class="fc-day-content"><div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div></div></div></td><td class="fc-day fc-mon fc-widget-content fc-past" data-date="2019-12-09"><div><div class="fc-day-number">9</div><div class="fc-day-content"><div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div></div></div></td><td class="fc-day fc-tue fc-widget-content fc-past" data-date="2019-12-10"><div><div class="fc-day-number">10</div><div class="fc-day-content"><div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div></div></div></td><td class="fc-day fc-wed fc-widget-content fc-past" data-date="2019-12-11"><div><div class="fc-day-number">11</div><div class="fc-day-content"><div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div></div></div></td><td class="fc-day fc-thu fc-widget-content fc-past" data-date="2019-12-12"><div><div class="fc-day-number">12</div><div class="fc-day-content"><div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div></div></div></td><td class="fc-day fc-fri fc-widget-content fc-past" data-date="2019-12-13"><div><div class="fc-day-number">13</div><div class="fc-day-content"><div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div></div></div></td><td class="fc-day fc-sat fc-widget-content fc-past fc-last" data-date="2019-12-14"><div><div class="fc-day-number">14</div><div class="fc-day-content"><div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div></div></div></td></tr><tr class="fc-week"><td class="fc-day fc-sun fc-widget-content fc-past fc-first" data-date="2019-12-15"><div style="min-height: 39px;"><div class="fc-day-number">15</div><div class="fc-day-content"><div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div></div></div></td><td class="fc-day fc-mon fc-widget-content fc-past" data-date="2019-12-16"><div><div class="fc-day-number">16</div><div class="fc-day-content"><div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div></div></div></td><td class="fc-day fc-tue fc-widget-content fc-past" data-date="2019-12-17"><div><div class="fc-day-number">17</div><div class="fc-day-content"><div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div></div></div></td><td class="fc-day fc-wed fc-widget-content fc-past" data-date="2019-12-18"><div><div class="fc-day-number">18</div><div class="fc-day-content"><div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div></div></div></td><td class="fc-day fc-thu fc-widget-content fc-past" data-date="2019-12-19"><div><div class="fc-day-number">19</div><div class="fc-day-content"><div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div></div></div></td><td class="fc-day fc-fri fc-widget-content fc-past" data-date="2019-12-20" style="color: rgb(255, 106, 106);"><div><div class="fc-day-number">20</div><div class="fc-day-content"><div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div></div></div></td><td class="fc-day fc-sat fc-widget-content fc-past fc-last" data-date="2019-12-21" style="color: rgb(255, 106, 106);"><div><div class="fc-day-number">21</div><div class="fc-day-content"><div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div></div></div></td></tr><tr class="fc-week"><td class="fc-day fc-sun fc-widget-content fc-past fc-first" data-date="2019-12-22"><div style="min-height: 39px;"><div class="fc-day-number">22</div><div class="fc-day-content"><div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div></div></div></td><td class="fc-day fc-mon fc-widget-content fc-past" data-date="2019-12-23"><div><div class="fc-day-number">23</div><div class="fc-day-content"><div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div></div></div></td><td class="fc-day fc-tue fc-widget-content fc-past" data-date="2019-12-24"><div><div class="fc-day-number">24</div><div class="fc-day-content"><div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div></div></div></td><td class="fc-day fc-wed fc-widget-content fc-past" data-date="2019-12-25"><div><div class="fc-day-number">25</div><div class="fc-day-content"><div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div></div></div></td><td class="fc-day fc-thu fc-widget-content fc-past" data-date="2019-12-26"><div><div class="fc-day-number">26</div><div class="fc-day-content"><div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div></div></div></td><td class="fc-day fc-fri fc-widget-content fc-past" data-date="2019-12-27" style="color: rgb(255, 106, 106);"><div><div class="fc-day-number">27</div><div class="fc-day-content"><div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div></div></div></td><td class="fc-day fc-sat fc-widget-content fc-past fc-last" data-date="2019-12-28" style="color: rgb(255, 106, 106);"><div><div class="fc-day-number">28</div><div class="fc-day-content"><div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div></div></div></td></tr><tr class="fc-week"><td class="fc-day fc-sun fc-widget-content fc-today fc-state-highlight fc-first" data-date="2019-12-29"><div style="min-height: 39px;"><div class="fc-day-number">29</div><div class="fc-day-content"><div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div></div></div></td><td class="fc-day fc-mon fc-widget-content fc-future" data-date="2019-12-30" style="background-color: rgb(188, 237, 145); cursor: pointer;"><div><div class="fc-day-number">30</div><div class="fc-day-content"><div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div></div></div></td><td class="fc-day fc-tue fc-widget-content fc-future" data-date="2019-12-31" style="background-color: rgb(188, 237, 145); cursor: pointer;"><div><div class="fc-day-number">31</div><div class="fc-day-content"><div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div></div></div></td><td class="fc-day fc-wed fc-widget-content fc-other-month fc-future" data-date="2020-01-01" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><div><div class="fc-day-number">1</div><div class="fc-day-content"><div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div></div></div></td><td class="fc-day fc-thu fc-widget-content fc-other-month fc-future" data-date="2020-01-02" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><div><div class="fc-day-number">2</div><div class="fc-day-content"><div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div></div></div></td><td class="fc-day fc-fri fc-widget-content fc-other-month fc-future" data-date="2020-01-03" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><div><div class="fc-day-number">3</div><div class="fc-day-content"><div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div></div></div></td><td class="fc-day fc-sat fc-widget-content fc-other-month fc-future fc-last" data-date="2020-01-04" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><div><div class="fc-day-number">4</div><div class="fc-day-content"><div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div></div></div></td></tr><tr class="fc-week fc-last"><td class="fc-day fc-sun fc-widget-content fc-other-month fc-future fc-first" data-date="2020-01-05" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><div style="min-height: 41px;"><div class="fc-day-number">5</div><div class="fc-day-content"><div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div></div></div></td><td class="fc-day fc-mon fc-widget-content fc-other-month fc-future" data-date="2020-01-06" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><div><div class="fc-day-number">6</div><div class="fc-day-content"><div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div></div></div></td><td class="fc-day fc-tue fc-widget-content fc-other-month fc-future" data-date="2020-01-07" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><div><div class="fc-day-number">7</div><div class="fc-day-content"><div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div></div></div></td><td class="fc-day fc-wed fc-widget-content fc-other-month fc-future" data-date="2020-01-08" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><div><div class="fc-day-number">8</div><div class="fc-day-content"><div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div></div></div></td><td class="fc-day fc-thu fc-widget-content fc-other-month fc-future" data-date="2020-01-09" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><div><div class="fc-day-number">9</div><div class="fc-day-content"><div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div></div></div></td><td class="fc-day fc-fri fc-widget-content fc-other-month fc-future" data-date="2020-01-10" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><div><div class="fc-day-number">10</div><div class="fc-day-content"><div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div></div></div></td><td class="fc-day fc-sat fc-widget-content fc-other-month fc-future fc-last" data-date="2020-01-11" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><div><div class="fc-day-number">11</div><div class="fc-day-content"><div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div></div></div></td></tr></tbody></table></div></div></div>
                    </td>
```